# File Encoding - Mysterious "?" Mark and "ILLEGAL Token" Error Messages

Tags: javascript, html, token

Come across this once in awhile.

Unpacked a zip file sent to me by a coworker. Loaded it up on my tomcat server to find out that there's this weird question mark at the beginning of the included JS file, preventing the JS file from being included properly.

I resaved the HTML file and the JS as new files and made sure encoding was UTF-8 and the line breaks were UNIX style.

Now I see the "ILLEGAL Token" error in Chrome and FF. Any ideas why?

EDIT:
Adding JS that is causing the issue. Anything inherently wrong with this? Per a comment, I think the removal of BOM fixed the issue but still getting the "ILLEGAL Token" message.

```
if(typeof deconcept=="undefined"){var deconcept=new Object();}
```

Comment: What makes you think that line is the line responsible for the "illegal token" error?  Have you looked at the source file to see if there are other odd characters in it?

Comment: It was the only line in the file. :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hard to say with much confidence, but weird characters at the start of text files are very often the Byte Order Mark (BOM). See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_Order_Mark. Some software handles them well, and you see nothing, other software doesn't handle them correctly and you see weird characters.

Comment: Updated my original post per your Byte Order Mark comment. That was what fixed the "?" error but still getting the ILLEGAL token error. :(